# Container div doesn't adjust to child Angular component height

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the below Ionic application [example in Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-wk9851). You'll see that there are a custom Angular component called `<my-video></my-video>`, an `ion-list` and a button. What I want is:

- Put the `ion-list` on top of the video. This way, the `ion-list` overlaps the video.
- Put the button under the video.

This is what I have now, you can see the code in the Stackblitz example (including the CSS code):

[image]

I think the problem can be that `video-container` hasn't the same height as its children `my-video`, but I don't know why.

[image]

I tried with different positioning configurations (position `relative`, `absolute` , `static`, etc.) with no effect.What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: I don't have access to images, could you explain what you want ? The list should overlap the video, and the video should overlap the button, but they should keep the position they have in your stackblitz ?

Comment: The list should overlap the video, and the button should be shown under the video. In the Stackblitz is what I have get so far, but it isn't what I want.

Comment: So the button would be hidden ? and the list should take all the width of the video ?

Comment: It has no height due to some CSS positioning other than static used (absolute in your case).

Comment: @trichetriche sorry, maybe is my English. I meant the button should appear below the video. And yes, the list should take all the width of the video.

Comment: So the video should be hidden by the list, and the button below it, that's all of your requirements ?

Comment: Yes. Just to clarify, the button should be below the video as you say, but it (the button) shouldn't overlap the list in anyway.

Comment: Something like this ? https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-a9i5ro?file=pages/home/home.scss

Comment: Yeah! If you put your solution in a comment, I'd accept it as the solving answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `my-video` is absolutely positioned, meaning it is taken out of the natural flow of positioning and positioning the button anywhere based on `my-video` very tricky, which is not what we want, so you need to make `my-video`'s positioning relative, keep the options-list position absolute but also add top: 0 and left: 0, like so

```
.video-container {
    position: relative;

    my-video {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .options-list {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}

.finish-button-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    position: relative;
}
```

now the button can go to the bottom of the screen because `my-video` is in the flow of positioning

Answer (score 0):

Updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ndw3ew?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.scss) with the following css for your button :

```
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
left: 50%;
right: 50%;
```

You need to use `position: absolute` here in order to get your button's position relative to the `.video-container` div.

Comment: Your solution works if I keep the same window size or the same video size. But, if either of them changes, the button loses the desired position.